# Checkbox filter using Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, filter

In my application there is a filter option with checkboxes.Checkboxes indicates top five categories and all other categories under another single checkbox.That means total I have six checkboxes(top five + other).When all checked which will fetch all values from database table and when all unchecked which never fetch any values from table.Please anybody give any suggestions for my unchecked case...What will be the condition there?

Comment: in order to give you a suggestion on the condition please provide your application code

Answer (score 0):

In the unchecked case i wouldn't do a mysql query - cause it is not necessary and you can save that time. Depending on your application and your code you need to implement a switch here and insert the result on your page as if no result (or entry) has been found. For further details more application code is needed.